# How can I target a <select> form element by name with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 3 form elements

```
<select name="closing_date[]"></select>
```

These are generated so cannot add a class or id, my css does nothing

```
select[name=closing_date] {
  width: 33% !important;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: For exact match: `select[name="closing_date[]"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/wMv4E/1/)

Try:

```
select[name^=closing_date] {
  width: 33% !important;
  background: red;
}
```

See [this article from MDN on attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> [attr^=value]
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
>   whose value is prefixed by "value".

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
select[name="closing_date[]"] {
    width: 33% !important;
    background: red;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/72PaM/)

Answer (score 0):

this is also work:

html

```
<select name="closing_date[]"></select>
<select name="closing_date[]"></select>
<select name="closing_date[]"></select>
```

css

```
select[name='closing_date[]'] {
  width: 33% !important;
  background: red;
}
```